# Base64 Error in encoding, bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python, base64

```
import base64
mycode = "print 'Hello World!'"
secret = base64.b64encode(mycode)
print(secret)
```

This code doesn't work it says bytes-like object is required, not 'str'.
Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message says, the encoder is expecting bytes, not a string. So convert the string to bytes.

```
>>> secret = base64.b64encode(bytes(mycode,"UTF-8"))
>>> secret
b'cHJpbnQgJ0hlbGxvIFdvcmxkISc='
>>> base64.b64decode(secret)
b"print 'Hello World!'"
```

Are you maybe following example code that assumes you are working in Python 2?

Comment: *Doesn't work* is not much to go on. What happens, what error message do you get?

Comment: ```
import base64
mycode = "print 'Hello World!'"
secret = base64.b64encode(bytes(mycode, "UTF-8"))
print(secret)
```

Comment: and in the end there is print(secret) but when I run the code nothing happens

Comment: When I run it in PyCharm it works fine. Is your PyCharm configuration running the program you think it is running? It reports the program it is running as the first line in the run window, like this: `"C:\Program Files\Python39\python.exe" "C:/Users/BoarGules/Documents/Python Projects/StackOverflow-3.9/65416833/65701859.py"`